# SQL Server split string values into rows and columns and insert into table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a string/text element that I need to split and insert into a table.

I have the text values of

```
123456|House,123567|Flat,789463|Car,635491|Lorry,
```

Where the number value (nvalue) needs to go in the first column, and the type eg. House needs to be in the second.

The values before the "," need to be on the same row. I would be looking for a table resembling

```
╔══════════╦═══════════╗
║ nvalue   ║ Type      ║
╠══════════╬═══════════╣
║   123456 ║     House ║
║   123567 ║      Flat ║
║   789463 ║       Car ║
║   635491 ║     Lorry ║
╚══════════╩═══════════╝
```

I'm trying to use the SQL code

```
INSERT INTO TABLE resultsTable
SELECT 
nvalue({status}, ';')[255],
type({status}| ';')[255],
```

but i'm not having any luck.

`{status}` is a text field where the string is located.

Comment: SQL Server 2016 has a split function to do this.

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server 2016+ you can use `string_split()`.

In SQL Server pre-2016, using a CSV Splitter table valued function by Jeff Moden along with `left()` and `stuff()` (or `right()`) with `charindex()`:

```
declare @status nvarchar(max) = '123456|House,123567|Flat,789463|Car,635491|Lorry,'

select 
    nvalue = left(s.Item,charindex('|',s.Item)-1)
  , [Type] = stuff(s.Item,1,charindex('|',s.Item),'')
from dbo.DelimitedSplitN4K(@status,',') s
where s.Item <>''
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/QQZUC78477

returns:

```
+--------+-------+
| nvalue | Type  |
+--------+-------+
| 123456 | House |
| 123567 | Flat  |
| 789463 | Car   |
| 635491 | Lorry |
+--------+-------+
```

splitting strings reference:

- [Tally OH! An Improved SQL 8K “CSV Splitter” Function - Jeff Moden](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/)
- [Splitting Strings : A Follow-Up - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/08/t-sql-queries/splitting-strings-follow-up)
- [Split strings the right way – or the next best way - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings)
- [**`string_split()`** in SQL Server 2016 : Follow-Up #1 - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlperformance.com/2016/04/sql-server-2016/string-split-follow-up-1)
- [Ordinal workaround for **`string_split()**` - Solomon Rutzky](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/Feedback/Details/2433171)

Answer (score 0):

You can either use `split()` from the web or in SQL Server 2016.  Then:

```
with lines(line) as (
      select l.*
      from dbo.split(@str, '|') l
     )
insert into resultsTable (nvalue, type)
    select left(line, charindex(',', line) - 1),
           stuff(line, charindex(',', line), len(line), '')
    from lines;
```

Answer (score 0):

Using SUBSTRING(), Xml and Cross apply we can get desired result

```
DECLARE @Value NVARCHAR(max) = ',123456|House,123567|Flat,789463|Car,635491|Lorry,'
DECLARE @DYVALUE TABLE (VALUE NVARCHAR(MAX))

INSERT INTO @DYVALUE (VALUE)
SELECT @VALUE

;WITH cte
AS (
    SELECT Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(1000)') AS Value
    FROM (
        SELECT CAST('<S>' + REPLACE(Value, ',', '</S><S>') + '</S>' AS XML) AS Value
        FROM @DyValue
        ) AS A
    CROSS APPLY Value.nodes('/S') AS Split(a)
    )
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT SUBSTRING(Value, 0, CHARINDEX('|', Value)) AS nvalue
        ,SUBSTRING(Value, CHARINDEX('|', Value) + 1, LEN(Value)) AS [Type]
    FROM Cte
    ) DT
WHERE nvalue <> ''
    AND [Type] <> ''
```

Result:

```
+--------+-------+
| nvalue | Type  |
+--------+-------+
| 123456 | House |
| 123567 | Flat  |
| 789463 | Car   |
| 635491 | Lorry |
+--------+-------+
```

Comment: I'm using SQL server 2012 (sorry should have mentioned that), but this works really well. The only issue is i'm having trouble adding the values to database resultsTable.

Do you know how I can take the result and put it into a specific SQL table.

I've tried 

    Insert INTO  resultsTable (nvalue, type)
    Value (nvalue, [type])

but it just shoots out an error

Comment: I managed to get this working by adding "INSERT INTO resultsTable" 

Changing the code to look like 

"CROSS APPLY Value.nodes('/S') AS Split(a)
    )
  insert into Missed_Collective_Events
SELECT *
FROM ("